# PDF display and URL redirection from WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, adobe, axacropdf

Hi I am creating a PDF viewer in my WPF application using AxAcroPDF. The PDF displayed correctly , but the hyperlink in the PDF content is not redirecting to external website when clicking on it. Any one knows the reason for that or how to redirect to external website from the PDF content when user click the hyperlink in the PDF?

Answer (score 0):

Is you PDF is a PDF text or as image?
If it's as image, you can't.

Otherwise, with the PdfPrintingNet library, it work's perfectly.

[PdfPrintingNet library web site](https://www.pdfprinting.net/viewer)

Regards.

Comment: Its a text. Is this a paid tool ?

Comment: Unfortunately yes it's a paid tool, someghings like 300$.